# How to set default output path `site-cookbooks` when using `knife cookbook create`

Tags: chef-infra, knife

Is there way to set default output path `cookbooks` to `site-cookbooks` when I run `knife cookbook create`?

I wrote `cookbook_path` in `~/.chef/knife.rb` like this.

```
cookbook_path ['./site-cookbooks']
```

But this doesn't change default cookbook output path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File expansion can be wonky in Ruby sometimes. If your `site-cookbooks` directory is at `~/site-cookbooks`, then you could put in something like this in your knife.rb:

```
current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
cookbook_path ["#{current_dir}/../site-cookbooks"]
```

Comment: I changed `knife.rb` setting as you wrote, but when I run `knife cookbook create something`, the receipt is created at `cookbook` as before, not in `site-cookbooks`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have multiple knife.rb files? Do you have multiple cookbook_path lines in your knife.rb?

Comment: Great! That was the problem. I only changed my home directory knife.rb , but there is also in my current chef repository that I didn't notice.